# c# VS CODE: добавить библиотеку

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Доброго времени суток. Суть проблемы: редактор VS Code не может увидеть ссылку на библиотеку, к примеру, добавив в юзинг `System.Collections` и при попытке использовать `ArrayList` , то за этим последует ошибка следующего характера: "ArrayList - неизвестный объект". При попытке написать `System.Collections.ArrayList` интелисенс ничего не видит. Также, нашел в OmniSharpe все необходимые библиотеки, но как их подключить в VS Code -- мне неизвестно, в чем, собственно, и состоит вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET Core стандартная библиотека распределена по множеству nuget-пакетов. Необобщенные коллекции (в том числе и `ArrayList`) находятся в пакете `System.Collections.NonGeneric`. Для подключения пакета необходимо добавить строку в файл `project.json`:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Comment: А что за "4.0.1"?

Comment: @Pepsi4 это версия